# increasing complexity of field decreases distinct values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Why am I getting less rows returned when I increase the complexity of the field?**

I need to merge 2 tables with the same schema.

**The problem is that the PK for the same records are not the same**

For example, I am trying to merge these two tables:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
|              columna                 |columnb | columnc  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| EE75442D-C41F-4AE4-A0B5-8459E3CBDEAC | donkey |        3 |
| 7E27434F-BC62-489B-97F4-7685BDA663D7 | horse  |        5 |
| 2344CB35-D4BB-4BFA-8869-797A8BE7C235 | cat    |        3 |
| DDB81938-D6A1-4435-96F2-C901785C5216 | cat    |        4 |
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
```

And this one:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
|              columna                 |columnb | columnc  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| BF01AD4B-0FBF-4653-9E02-20C640451AF8 | donkey |        3 |
| 7A8ED2BD-F844-49A9-B8EC-37B360030580 | horse  |        5 |
| 1CDB2B1A-AB8F-44D6-A933-B12A6FE87D71 | cat    |        3 |
| D8D98F48-9BDF-4009-96AF-76DEC49E0856 | cat    |        4 |
+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
```

I have a nice primary key in both tables:**columna**

Unfortunately, it is useless because I have not kept the same PK for the same record.

I was trying to find a combination of fields that I could concatonate and create a unique field. For example, this will return 303139 records:

```
;with cte_unique as (
       select (cast (parentcustomerid as  NVARCHAR(36)) + vth_contactnumber)  as uniqueColumn from contact)

       select COUNT(distinct uniquecolumn) from cte_unique
```

Whereas, when I increase the complexity of the field by concatonating another field to **uniquecolumn**:

```
   ;with cte_unique as (
   select (cast (parentcustomerid as  NVARCHAR(36)) + vth_contactnumber+mobilephone)  as uniqueColumn from contact)

   select COUNT(distinct uniquecolumn) from cte_unique
```

**I actually get less rows ** 160981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't concatenate. concatenating `NULL` results in `NULL`. Try

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT parentcustomerid,
                         vth_contactnumber,
                         mobilephone
         FROM   contact)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   CTE
```

And if that combination is unique you can use a join on

```
SELECT *
FROM   contact c
       JOIN other_table t
         ON EXISTS(SELECT t.parentcustomerid,
                          t.vth_contactnumber,
                          t.mobilephone
                   INTERSECT
                   SELECT c.parentcustomerid,
                          c.vth_contactnumber,
                          c.mobilephone)
```

Comment: wow! that is so cool. can you explain how that intersect/exists works?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - I stole it from [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx). It works on the basis that for example `SELECT 1, NULL INTERSECT SELECT 1, NULL` will return a row because column by column they are the same (treating `NULL=NULL` as true). Except instead of using literal values it references columns from the outer query.